# How to add user role class on link of each user name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching for this but didn't find anything. I want to add the same user role class to the link of each user. i.e. if user is "Admin" or "Subscriber" then the class should be `<a href="http://example.com" class="admin">User</a>` or `<a href="http://example.com" class="subscriber">User</a>`

Please see attachment.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [get_userdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function can be used to achieve this.

```
<?php
      $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
      $first_name = $user_info->first_name;
      $user_role = $user_info->roles;
      echo '<a href="#" class="' . $user_role  . '"> . $first_name  . </a>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need this done in functions.php because users are dynamically showing on different places i.e. comment sections, posts sections

Comment: You can very well use this code snippet in your functions.php file to achieve the result you want.

Comment: Please see attachment.

Comment: Looks like you're using a plugin to insert that data. Find the code for that plugin and extend it through a filter.